# why most of games from google market do not execute on android x86?

Tags: android, android-x86

I installed android x86 on virtual box. Also to test it I download some games from google market. But most of them do not execute. Why most of games from google market do not execute on android x86?

Comment: most probably because they use third party (or their own) native (c/c++) libraries which are CPU-architecture dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most games use native code, whether directly or because they use a system such as Mono or Unity which is itself built upon native code.  If the apk you are running does not have the native code included compiled for the processor architecture you are running then the code will not run.

Physical x86 based phone often have a translation layer that they have licenced so that they **can** run ARM native code (at much reduced speed) on x86, but it's unlikely that virtual box will include this.

In addition, you do not say how you are putting your games on to the virtual box.  If you are installing them on a ARM phone device, and then transferring them to the x86 virtual box, it's possible that the Play Store has decided to serve you up an ARM specific version of the game.  If you install directly from the Play Store (which is hard to achieve with a virtual system) then you may find more apps do have x86 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Android does not have the hardware abstraction layer that Windows has so if the games require graphics, for example, it may not support many of the components that are on your system.  This is why it takes so long to get Android updates from our phone carriers-they have to make sure the latest builds will actually run on our many devices.