# why most of games from google market do not execute on android x86 but execute on device with androidx86?

Tags: android, virtualbox

Some time ago I have posted the question [why most of games from google market do not execute on android x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132433/why-most-of-games-from-google-market-do-not-execute-on-android-x86). I tested a lot of games on Virtual Box version of android x86 and they did not run. Yesterday I toke megafon mint ( android version 2.3, intel Atom). And there was all games was run, even those which was not run on VB. Why is it ?

Answer (score 0):

Consumer devices running on Intel platforms all are able to execute arm code thanks to a "NDK apps bridging technology".
The Megafon Mint was one of the first devices available. This technology has improved a lot since then. Now the overhead of this is quite low and it can execute armv7 instructions.